# Javascript recursive setTimeout not using updated values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have been trying to work with setInterval for increasing a progress bar, but the problem is that, as I am using React Native, the JS thread can't execute all my animations until the progress bar task has finished.

So, that is why I am trying to make the same operation with a recursive setTimeout, but the problem is that it seems to consume the global context (not sure, but the data is not updated)... Here is what I am doing:

```
  const [timerProgress, setTimerProgress] = useState(0);

  const advanceTimer = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTimerProgress(timerProgress + 1 / 30); // <-------- timerProgress seems to be not updated (most of the times is 0) when recursion
      if (timerProgress < 1) {
        advanceTimer();
      }
    }, 1000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (rival) {
      // When a new rival is found, we stop the 'fetching' action
      setIsFetching(false);

      // Only update the timer if there is a rival
      advanceTimer();
    }
  }, [rival]);
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: timerProgress is always in the "global" context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimerProgress` is the asynchronous function, and you can't get the updated value immediately after `setTimerProgress`.
You should get it in `useEffect` with passing the `timerProgress` variable dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(timerProgress);
}, [timerProgress])
```

Comment: Okey, thank you, seems that I will have to use useEffect or pass the most recent value as argument to the recursion calls.

Comment: You can use a custom hook too to solve this issue. Just pass a callback, where you run your conditional recursion call, to useStateWithCallback. https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usestate-callback